# Is it possible to send a file from a client to restler.file?

Tags: node.js, express, restler, busboy

Normally restler.post() takes a restler.file(...) object to send a POST. This works if you have the file path on the server.

For example:

```
//#############################################################################
// Video upload from file system on node console server
//#############################################################################

function(done){

  var fileStats = fs.statSync(videoFileName);
  var fileSizeInBytes = fileStats["size"];

  var data = {
    'name': objectVideoName,
    'type':'video',
    'content': 'application/mp4',
    'file': restler.file(videoFileName, null, fileSizeInBytes, null, "video" )
  };


  restler.post('https://api.astra.io/v0/bucket/'+bucketName+'/object', {
    multipart: true,
    data   : data,
    headers : { "Astra-Secret": astraSecret }
  }).on('complete', function(response) {
    console.log('Upload video to bucket: \n', response);
    done(null);
  });

},
```

How can I POST the file from the client directly without saving it on the server?

I'm trying with busboy.

```
//#############################################################################
// Video upload from client then POST to cdn
//#############################################################################
app.post('/addVideo', function (req, res) {

var video = {};
var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});

busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

    var ext = mimetype.split('/').pop();
    var token = generateToken(crypto);

    var fileSizeInBytes = 900000;

    filename = token + ext;

    var videoName = filename;

    var bucketName = 'sampleVideos';

    var data = {
      'name': videoName,
      'type':'video',
      'content': 'application/mp4',
      'file': ***** WHAT GOES HERE ******
    };

    restler.post('https://api.astra.io/v0/bucket/'+bucketName+'/object', {
      multipart: true,
      data   : data,
      headers : { "Astra-Secret": astraSecret }
    }).on('complete', function(response) {
      console.log('Upload video to bucket: \n', response);
      res.send("200");
    });

});

busboy.on('field', function (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
    video[fieldname] = val;
});

busboy.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('busboy finished');
});

req.pipe(busboy);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two helper functions exported  by `restler` to help create your data options. You don't use either and specify a JS Object literal. `restler.data()` is what you want to use

```
data: function(filename, contentType, data) {
    return new Data(filename, contentType, data);
}
```

So instead of

```
var data = {
  'name': videoName,
  'type':'video',
  'content': 'application/mp4',
  'file': ***** WHAT GOES HERE ******
};
```

in your example you would do this as it allows you to use arbitrary content instead of a file name

```
var data = restler.data(videoName, 'application/mp4', file);
```

Comment: The question already includes that. The question is how to feed a stream from busboy to restler.

Comment: No, you use a JS object literal. I'll update the answer to make the answer clearer.

Comment: You might also need to wait for ``file.on('data', function(incomingData){})`` to actually have the content of the file.